# Adjustbox MWE does not compile

Tags: adjustbox

This is taken from the `adjustbox` manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

Before
\adjustbox{padding*=1ex 2ex 3ex 4ex,frame,margin*=1ex 2ex 3ex 4ex}{Text}
After

\end{document}
```

But it does not work here.

What am I missing?

TeX Live 14 full updated.

Log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.9.26)  30 SEP 2014 15:47
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**tex-se3.tex
(./tex-se3.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 9 languages loaded.
(/home/franz/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/franz/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (./adjustbox.sty) (./tex-se3.aux)
\openout1 = `tex-se3.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \adjustbox
              {padding*=1ex 2ex 3ex 4ex,frame,margin*=1ex 2ex 3ex 4ex}{Text}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[1

{/home/franz/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./tex-se3.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 208 strings out of 494900
 2253 string characters out of 6178175
 47324 words of memory out of 5000000
 3521 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 81 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,4n,17p,137b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</home/franz/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/
cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on tex-se3.pdf (1 page, 15025 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 12 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? I get the same result as in the manual.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It says "undefined control sequence". I reinstalled the package, just in case, but it still does not work!

Comment: Exactly what does it say, could you update your question and paste the compilation log from that exact example?

Comment: @dailef I attached the full log

Comment: OMG, found it! I had another file called "adjustbox.sty" (written by me) in the compilation directory! What should I do? Delete this?

Comment: You could delete or you could answer it, note the log file you showed showed you had a local copy of the file in the current directory `(./adjustbox.sty)` it's always worth checking the log:-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a local version of a file that caused the problem. It may not be applicable to a wider audience.

Comment: @Werner it can be closed for me, np

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I created an `adjustbox.sty` file into my compilation folder (and then I forgot about it) so my custom sty file was read instead of the TeX Live one.

As David Carlisle noted, the log pointed out that it was reading the local sty file.